# How to do prediction for regression analysis with multiple target variable

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have a bike rental dataset. In this dataset our target variable is Count i.e. total count of bike rental which is the sum of two variables in our dataset i.e casual user count variable and registered user count variable.
So my question is how should i perform modelling on this dataset ?
Please suggest a step as I'm thinking of dropping casual and registered user variable and keeping only count variable as our tagert variable along with other predictor variables

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and what your *exact* issue is

Comment: total users = casual + registered, so model either one and the other equals (total - model prediction).

Comment: @JamesPhillips thanks man i got it....i am currently concerned about the total bike rental count...hence i will go with total count and will remove casual user count variable and registered user count variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is rather vague but I will attempt to answer it.

I am not too sure what it is that you want to predict. Assuming it is the amount of bikes that would be rented out at some future time.

If the distinction between *casual* and *registered*  is important and has significant meaning to the purpose of your project, then you should probably treat them as separate features and not combine them into one.

On the contrary, if the distinction is not important and you only care for the amount of bikes, then you should be fine combining them and using the total sum.

I think you should try to understand what you are trying to accomplish and what questions you wish to answer with your analysis.

Comment: As i am only concerned about the total count of bike hence i will develop my model considering total count as my target variable and i will remove the registered user count variable and casual user Count from my dataset for model preparation..

Answer (score 0):

Converted my two target variables into one by summing them up and then created a new model with only one target variable.